# CS1501 "No overload for method `Weight' takes `0' arguments"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I am getting the following error with the following classes in Unity Engine.

Error:

```
No overload for method 'Weight' takes '0' arguments
```

Child class:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CreateHammerstone : MonoBehaviour {



private BaseTool newTool;

void Start(){
    Debug.Log (newTool.Weight());

}



public void CreateTool() {

    newTool = new BaseTool ();

    //assign name to tool
    newTool.ItemName = "Hammer Stone";
    //Create a weapon description
    newTool.ItemDescription = "The Hammer Stone is a rather universal blunt tool that is primarly used to strike off lithic flakes in the procces of stone tool crafting. Alternatively it can also be used to breaking hard nuts,shells etc. Or executing small prey"; 
    //Tool ID
    newTool.ItemID = 1;
    //stats
    newTool.Density = 2.6f; //gram pr cm3 
    newTool.Volume = 360f;  //cm3
    newTool.Weight(newTool.Density, newTool.Volume); // HERE IS THE ISSUE!!!!
    //Choose type of Tool
    newTool.ToolType = BaseTool.ToolTypes.CRAFTING;

}
}
```

Parent class:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BaseStatsItem : BaseItem {

private float volume;
private float density;
private int willPower;
private int perception;
private int intelligence;




public float Volume {
    get {return volume;}
    set {volume = value;} 
}
public float Density {
    get { return density;}
    set { density = value;}
}

public int WillPower{
    get {return willPower;}
    set {willPower = value;}
}
public int Perception{
    get {return perception;}
    set {perception = value;}
}
public int Intelligence{
    get {return intelligence;}
    set {intelligence = value;}
}

public float Weight(float density, float volume){ // here is the function!!
    float sum = density * volume;
    return sum;  
}




}
```

As you can see it seems like it takes no arguments. I guess it's because volume and density is assigned at the same time as the weight function, so their is still no information for the weight function to retrieve. Am I right? and how do I fix that?

Comment: "As you can see it seems like it takes no arguments." Um, no, it looks like it has two parameters: `public float Weight(float density, float volume)`. It looks like it *shouldn't* need parameters, but it does have them. You should also look into automatically implemented properties, which would make your code drastically shorter.

Comment: ^ and where is the `BaseTool` ?

Comment: And the problematic line is `Debug.Log (newTool.Weight());` not `newTool.Weight(newTool.Density, newTool.Volume);` - the latter should compile with no problems...

Comment: @JonSkeet you are right, removing the parameters did solve the error, I will search for implemented properties as you suggested and I fixed the debug log as Arghya C pointed out. Thanks!!